# At what point in size does gravity force a celestial body to become "round"?

Tags: gravity, astronomy

I am watching a video on asteroid size comparisons and I noticed that 2 Pallas (512 km) and 4 Vesta (525 km) are both "spherical" in shape (pretty much anyway).  However 52 Europa (319 km) is also pretty spherical.  Even 20 Massalia (145 km) appears to be part of a larger spherical asteroid that may have been broken.  Ceres at 939 km almost looks like a small moon.

So at what diameter does gravity force the object to become spherical?

Comment: [The potato radius](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1091)!

Comment: @JohnRennie That link is to this question.

Comment: @JohnRennie - I was confused too...  However I do not think the question is answered.  The answer says 1000 km  but there are many asteroids smaller that are round.  The paper for the potato radius is 200-300 km

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant this: [What is the minimum mass required so that objects become spherical due to its own gravity?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/what-is-the-minimum-mass-required-so-that-objects-become-spherical-due-to-its-ow)